# wp_embed_register_handler is not working

Tags: embed, oembed

I used this function for other video hosts, but for some reason, now it's not working. This is the direct and embed code of the video

```
https://vidoza.net/r2jeim68kuq6.html

<IFRAME SRC="https://vidoza.net/embed-r2jeim68kuq6.html" FRAMEBORDER=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 SCROLLING=NO WIDTH=640 HEIGHT=360 allowfullscreen></IFRAME>
```

and this is my registration function.

```
add_action( 'init', function()
{        wp_embed_register_handler(
        'vidoza', 
        '#https://vidoza\.net/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$#i',   
        'vidoza_embed_handler' 
    );
} );


function vidoza_embed_handler( $matches, $attr, $url, $rawattr )
{
    $embed = sprintf( 
        '<IFRAME SRC="https://vidoza.net/embed-%1$s" FRAMEBORDER=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 SCROLLING=NO WIDTH=640 HEIGHT=360 allowfullscreen></IFRAME>',
        esc_attr( $matches[1] )
    );
    return apply_filters( 'vidoza_embed_handler', $embed, $matches, $attr, $url, $rawattr );
}
```

I am not able to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to match the `r2jeim68kuq6.html` part, but you're not allowing dots in your regex pattern here:

```
'#https://vidoza\.net/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$#i'
```

You can try e.g. (removing the `A-Z` too because of the case-insensitive `i` search):

```
'#https://vidoza\.net/([a-z0-9_-]+)\.html$#i'
```

if `.html` is a standard extension and where you also adjust the iframe source to:

```
src="https://vidoza.net/embed-%1$s.html"
```

Hope it helps!